# Visual Studio Github Add One More Project

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-code, github-for-windows

There is a project I'm working on, blazor webassembly, and I'm working as a layered architecture in it. For some reason, visual studio sent only the frontend side to Github when creating a repo, it didn't send the server part, and how can I include this server part in that project?